# Оцените, пожалуйста, мою верстку

Tags: css3, html, вёрстка, css

http://websterjoy.tk/
Впервые сверстал на `html5`, как скажете? правильно ли все, семантично ли? Какие замечания вы могли бы сказать по поводу верстки?
CSS разумеется валидацию не проходит, т.к вендорные префиксы и т.д.

Comment: Выглядит качественно. 

Особо понравилось (большие буквы)

    Масло сливочное, Крестьянское 72,5 %
    Масса: 250 грамм
    
    Брэнд: Простоквашино

а ниже мелкими буквами описаниеЖ: 

    Испанское красное сладкое вино «Дом Беренгер» 1918 года классификации D.O.C. крепостью 20%. Производится из винограда: Гарнача. Можно пить сейчас или позже.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Моё мнение, которое не претендует на истину.

По поводу семантичности:

- Вы слишком увлеклись тэгом `section`, в большинстве случаев можно было спокойно использовать `div`.
- Для тэга `header` главного для страницы, рекомендуется использовать класс, например `.page-header` и уже от него настраивать разметку его содержимого.

По поводу самой вёрстки:

- Не используйте классы типа `.gray`, `.green`, `.black2` и т.д. Название класса должно быть осмысленным. То же самое касается и классов типа `fs12`, `fs14`, `fs16`. Их можно переименовать например в `font-size-small`, `font-size-medium` и т.д. Т.к. вы используете на сайте чаще размер шрифта в `12px`, то можно, например, такой размер задать по умолчанию для `body` и тогда код станет чище.
- Забудьте про `<div class="clear"></div>`, используйте `.clearfix`
- Не используйте `h3` для вывода цены и `h1` для количества упаковок, который у вас по счёту вторым получается, что недопустимо. Сеошники могут и побить :)
- Маленькие картинки объедините в `sprite` ( спрайты )
- Нет смысла использовать `float` с `display:inline-block` т.к. `float` делает элемент блочным (т.е. `display:block`).
- Определитесь с поддержкой браузеров, а то для `border-radius` вы поддерживаете аж FF 3.6 c префиксом `-moz`, хотя не делаете того же для `box-shadow` ( класс `.show_current` )
- я надеюсь вы используете `@import` только при разработке, а потом всё равно стили склеиваете.

Если что-то ещё замечу, обновлю пост.

Comment: Спасибо за очень ценный комментарий. 
И у меня возникли вопросы: почему нельзя использовать классы с цветами и размером шфита (.gray, .fs14)? ведь при верстке дописал этот класс и цвет или шрифт уже задавать не нужно. 
И что, все картинки маленькие объеденить в спрайт? там их около 6.

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста!
Потому что это не гибко. Может случится так, что вам нужно будет поменять размеры шрифта для блоков с .fs12 на 11px и вам придётся везде их переименовывать, а если вы этого не сделаете, то это осложнит дальнейшую поддержку кода. С цветами, аналогично, вдруг заказчик захочет вместо серого синий и т.д. В спрайт лучше объединять те картинки, которые используются в оформлении страницы и заданы через background. Не обязательно это делать вручную, есть куча сайтов, которым скарливаешь архив картинок и на выходе получаешь готовый спрайт и стили.

Comment: Это точно, хороший совет!

Answer (score 1):

`This document was successfully checked as HTML5!` Что тут еще скажешь) +1